# Adding 'total' property on JSON

Tags: php, json

In my project, I am fetching rows of data from the database and using json_encode to transform the data to JSON. I am echoing the JSON and so far it is displaying the correct result. Here is a sample:

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"test name","description":"test description","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema","email":"test@yahoo.com"}]}
```

Now, I want to insert a 'total' before the "results". The 'total' is the total entries of results. This will be the structure:

```
{"total":"1", "results":[{"id":"1","name":"test name","description":"test description","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema","email":"test@yahoo.com"}]}
```

The value of 'total' changes depending on how many items 'results' has. How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: In a JSON Object the order is irrelevant, it's because the access is by key and the order rarely is used. You can access directly to the "results" length `object.results.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe that the following code should work (if I understand what you're trying to do correctly): http://jsfiddle.net/obfa34mb/

```
var results = [
{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"test name","description":"test description","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema","email":"test@yahoo.com"}, {"id":"2","name2":"test name2","description2":"test description2","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema2","email2":"test2@yahoo.com"}]},
{"results":[{"id":"3","name3":"test name3","description3":"test description3","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema","email":"test3@yahoo.com"}, {"id":"4","name4":"test name4","description4":"test description","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema4","email4":"test4@yahoo.com"}]},    
];

var new_results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var item = {
        'total': results[i].results.length,
        'results': results[i].results
    };
    new_results.push(item);
}
console.log(new_results);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "How do I do this in PHP?"

Comment: The question is posed in Javascript (to wit: OP asks how to obtain a result in Javascript), and so this IS the way you'd do this in PHP or ASP.NET, or anything else. The server-side tech is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to achieve this:

```
<?php
  $obj = '{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"test name","description":"test description","db_hostname":"test hostname","db_schema":"test schema","email":"test@yahoo.com"}]}';
  $arr = json_decode($obj, true);

  $new_obj = json_encode( array_merge(array("total"=>count($arr['results'][0])), $arr ) );
  print_r($new_obj);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/315719)**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "How do I do this in PHP?"